# Как получить абсолютный путь к файлу и сам файл

Tags: golang

Как получить путь к файлу и сам файл? Код:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    dir, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(dir)
}
```

Данный код получает только текущую директорию, но не файл! Как мне получить директорию и текущий запущенный файл? То есть что-то типо такого должно быть: `C:\program\program.exe`

Answer (score 2):

Для этого есть функция [Executable](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Executable) из стандартного пакета `os`.

Описание:

> Executable returns the path name for the executable that started the current process. There is no guarantee that the path is still
>   pointing to the correct executable. If a symlink was used to start the
>   process, depending on the operating system, the result might be the
>   symlink or the path it pointed to. If a stable result is needed,
>   path/filepath.EvalSymlinks might help. Executable returns an absolute
>   path unless an error occurred. The main use case is finding resources
>   located relative to an executable. Executable is not supported on
>   nacl.

Answer (score 1):

Если проблема только в том что получается папка - просто уберите вызов filepath.Dir - этой функцией вы как раз отрезаете из пути имя файла и оставляете только папку.